# Behavior of a Spring session-scoped bean and a Java static object in a clustered environment

Tags: java, spring, session, static

In a clustered environment, I know that HttpSession objects migrate from one VM to another. But, what if I store information in a Spring session-scoped bean or store information in the static Map of a class? What happens to the stored data?

Answer (score 3):

Information stored in a static variable stays local to the classloader that loaded that class, it doesn't get migrated. Anything that you (or Spring) puts in the HttpSession gets migrated because the application server is responsible for providing the session and it knows where the other nodes are and it can be set up to do that in particular.

This is one of the reasons static variables (and roll-your-own caching) are problematic, because you can build an application with them that works fine on one server, but if you deploy it to multiple nodes it doesn't work as well because the caches aren't consistent with each other.

For migrating data that's not in your HttpSession, some kind of caching ([Spring supports plugging in different caching providers](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html)) has to be configured.

Comment: Question: What about a static object inside of a singleton-scoped bean?

Comment: @CM_2014: that would be local to one JVM too, it's not going to get copied to other nodes in the cluster.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation and the spring caching reference!

Answer (score 1):

The session replication configuration of your server cluster will replicate the session object from one node to the other. There are different session replication strategies as well.

With that said, the replication will happen if your Spring session bean is serializable. Your session scoped bean will be serializable only if the object reference what you make from the bean is also serializable. Serialization will happen only if the entire object tree is serializable.

You can make all non-session required references as transient if that fit to your requirement.